# How many members of the Jedi Order formally joined the Separatists?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In Canon, the Confederacy of Independent Systems had several former Jedi serving it in one capacity or another, the most prominent of whom was Count Dooku who formally left the Jedi Order then later publicly joined and ran the [CIS](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Confederacy_of_Independent_Systems). Dooku trained a [former Jedi Padawan, Asajj Ventress](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Asajj_Ventress#The_Lost_Sister) as a Sith Assassin, and Jedi General [Pong Krell](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pong_Krell) tried to sabotage the Jedi Order from within during the Clone Wars.

However out of all of these, only Dooku actually formally left the Jedi Order to join the CIS; Ventress was being trained as a Padawan away from the Jedi Temple and when [her master](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ky_Narec) was killed her training effectively ended on its own, and Pong Krell never formally resigned from the Jedi Order (and may never have actually formally joined the CIS either).

In Legends, several more former Jedi served the CIS as well:

- [Aurra Sing](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aurra_Sing/Legends) although she never formally left the Jedi Order.

And then the remaining members of Count Dooku's [Dark Acolytes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Acolyte):

- [Sora Bulq](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sora_Bulq/Legends) who was corrupted by Dooku and then led the Dark Acolytes.
- [Nikkos Tyris](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nikkos_Tyris) and two other unnamed Jedi who left the Order to form the [Jensaarai](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jensaarai).
- [Kadrian Sey](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kadrian_Sey) who refused to return to the Order during the outbreak of the Clone Wars and then was corrupted by Dooku.
- [Tol Skorr](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tol_Skorr) who was corrupted by Count Dooku and whose turn to the Dark side was known to the Order.

Although neither Asajj Ventress nor Aurra Sing formally left the Order, nor Pong Krell, it could be argued that the members of the Dark Acolytes essentially did even if they were turned to the Dark Side first by Count Dooku. My question therefore is, in addition to the above, did any other Jedi, in Legends or Canon, actually leave the Order, either before or during the Clone Wars, and join the CIS?

Although answers can include Jedi who at one point or another helped the CIS (i.e. Quinlan Vos who (in Legends) was corrupted by Dooku before being redeemed later on), I am really looking for Jedi (whether Padawans, Knights, or Masters) who permanently left the Order and then chose to fight for, or at least contribute to in some capacity, the Separatist Cause.